# Fetcing older posts through RSS feed

Tags: wordpress, rss

I have a **WordPress** website that publishes articles on a daily basis.
I have connected the website with a VOIP provider because some users want to access the website's content by **phone** (they are visually impaired).

The users dial a **landline number** and listen to the latest posts.  The VOIP provider fetches only a certain number of posts for each article category. The VoIP provider does that using WordPress RSS built-in engine.

So when a user visits a specific **category page**, he listens to the latest posts.
When he selects to listen to older posts he is being directed to the beginning.
My VoIP provider told me that I have to edit the RSS commands and make the RSS fetch older articles if requested.

I hope my post makes sense. What do I have to do?

I am trying to see IF I can do this through a WordPress plugin. I am reading some articles but none seems to address that issue. Except if I am missing something.

Comment: Please search if the WordPress RSS built-in engine supports parameters in order to set in those parameters the date range. As far as I know, RSS does not support this kind of behaviour = it brings the latest entries (*without storing older entries*).

Comment: Ok, Marco will do. Thanks a lot for your answer.